# JavaScript rethrowing an Exception preserving the stack trace

Tags: javascript, stack-trace, throw

In Chrome, when an exception occurs, it prints a stack trace to the console log. This is extremely useful, but unfortunately in cases where an exception has been rethrown this causes an issue.

```
} catch (e) {
    if (foo(e)) {
        // handle the exception
    } else {
        // The stack traces points here
        throw e;
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, the following code in `jQuery.js` is causing all exceptions to have this issue if they're from inside event handlers.

```
try {
    while( callbacks[ 0 ] ) {
        callbacks.shift().apply( context, args );
    }
}
// We have to add a catch block for
// IE prior to 8 or else the finally
// block will never get executed
catch (e) {
    throw e;
}
finally {
    fired = [ context, args ];
    firing = 0;
}
```

Is there a way to change the `throw e;` so that the exception is rethrown with the same stack trace?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I rethrow an exception in Javascript, but preserve the stack?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3734236/how-can-i-rethrow-an-exception-in-javascript-but-preserve-the-stack)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a [known bug in Chrome](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=60240), and unfortunately there's no workaround that I'm aware of.

Answer (score 1):

The best you can do is grab the original stack and print it.
I use this in unit testing tools.

```
try{
  ...
}
catch(e){
    console.log(e.stack);
    console.log(e.message);
    throw(e);
}
```

Comment: Note: According to this thread(https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=60240)
rethrowing works in Chrome now, but I find it only works in code defined in a single file. My rethrow is in a different file, and its not working.